# How to replacing style of UI element e.g table in Vaadin

Tags: styles, customization, vaadin

I would like to replace the style of custom table.

By using

```
  fooTable.setStyleName("v-tableII");
```

produces the following result

```
  <div class="v-table v-table-v-tableII v-tableII" ...
```

(grrr)

It would be important to replace the 'v-table' style because it belongs to another customized table.

Is there any way using different styles for different tables ?
(The help recommends to using addStyle, but the original 'v-table' style is tailored to another custom table )

Thanks for answers in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how vaadin works and you will always have that. You are using the correct option fooTable.setStyleName("v-tableII") but have you remember to add this to your css file? In some cases you might have to set !important on some of the options.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, this is my suggestion too according to the help. I will check what you told. All together overwriting styles of the used theme in significantly way is not recommended.